# Registered events maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

`shape.addListener( 'click', function() { alert('test1') });`

`shape.addListener( 'click', function() { alert('test2') });`

It is possible to use console.log() to view all functions registered events for a shape?

Where to find this information in the shape object or the api object ?

Example: `console.log( shape.listeners.registered )`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an inspector tool like firebug in your browser.

Inspecting the script  you can see all the object  in the analize section. For each of this  object you can see the properties including the added listner .